# How to call a Clojure variadic function from Java

Tags: java, clojure, interop, variadic-functions

Is it possible to declare a variadic function in Clojure that can be called as a varargs method from Java?

Consider this extract from some code under development:

```
(ns com.mydomain.expression.base 
  (:gen-class
    :name com.mydomain.expression.Base
    :methods [^:static [exprFactory [String String ?????] Object]]
  )

(defn expr-factory
  ; worker function that is also called from Clojure
  [id func & args]
  (let [ex ("construction code here")]
    ex))

(defn -exprFactory
  ; interface method called from Java
  [idStr funcStr & argsArray]
  (apply expr-factory idStr funcStr (seq argsArray)))
```

Is there anything I can put in place of `?????` to allow Java to call the `exprFactory` method and to know that it is a varargs method:

```
import com.mydomain.expression.Base;
...
Object e1 = Base.exprFactory("e1", "day");
Object e2 = Base.exprFactory("e2", "length", "string");
Object e3 = Base.exprFactory("e3", "*", 4, 5);
Object sum = Base.exprFactory("sum", "+", e1, e2, e3);
```

To make this a little clearer, I know I use `Object` in place of `?????` and change `exprFactory` to:

```
(defn -exprFactory
  ; interface method called from Java
  [idStr funcStr argsArray]
  (apply expr-factory idStr funcStr (seq argsArray)))
```

..but that means I have to write Java calls like this:

```
import com.mydomain.expression.Base;
...
Object e1 = Base.exprFactory("e1", "day", new Object[0] ));
Object e2 = Base.exprFactory("e2", "length", new Object[] { "string" }));
Object e3 = Base.exprFactory("e3", "*", new Integer[] { 4, 5 }));
Object sum = Base.exprFactory("sum", "+", new Object[] { e1, e2, e3 }));
```

Again, I know I could write a varargs wrapper method in Java that calls the non-variadic `exprFactory`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @andrew That was the first thing I tried, and I also tried Object... which would match the Java syntax.

Comment: since varargs are just a cheat by the compiler that just look like an array in the type signature, you should be able to specify a ``String[]`` with this: ``"[Ljava.lang.String;"`` instead of ``?????``. I tried that, it compiles, but eclipse won't recognized the varargs, it insists on a ``String[]`` even tho a java class and a gen-class class have identical type sigs. You might have more luck

Comment: I know it is possible because Datomic does this...

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible. I posted my investigation to the clojure ML - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/HMpMavh0WxA

Comment: @sw1nn Thanks for following this up further. I'd got as far as using your trick to force the Java side to provide the array but not with the preferred variadic syntax. It would be nice to have a clean way to do this from Clojure - perhaps `:methods [^:static [exprFactory [String String & Object] Object]]` and have Clojure automatically handle the interpretation of the array as a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing your helper function on the Java side, something like the "applyToHelper" in [clojure.lang.AFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java)

This would take the form of a Java function that looks something like:

```
   public Object invokeVariadic(IFn function, Object... args) {
     switch (args.length) {
       case 0:
         return function.invoke();
       case 1:
         return function.invoke(args[0]);
       /// 20-odd more cases
     }
   }
```

It's a bit of a hack and depends on the internal definition of [clojure.lang.IFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java), but at least you will get relatively nice variadic syntax on the Java side (i.e. no need to do the `new Object[] {...}` stuff).

Comment: I think that might be overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. For clarity, on the Clojure side I want to ultimately call `expr-factory` with an optional sequence of arguments (operands for an expression) - a ref to that sequence is stored in the returned `Object`. The `(apply ...)` form in the `-exprFactory` function is only used to expand the Java array. Perhaps there's a more efficient way to interface `-exprFactory` and `expr-factory` as I'm aware the args currently go from Java array -> sequence -> flattened arg list -> sequence.